# Using transform: scale results in blurry images

Tags: css, safari, transform, scale

In our catalog view (online store) we use javascript to get different views of the products and scale the images down with CSS. 
3 in a row / 4 or 5/

[image]

The default view is 4:

```
-webkit-transform: scale(0.83);
-moz-transform: scale(0.83);
-ms-transform: scale(0.83);
-o-transform: scale(0.83);
transform: scale(0.83);
```

Everything works but the images look very blurry in safari. Is there a way to improve the rendering for safari?
Bigger Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaFeB.jpg

[image]

Answer (score 48, accepted):

it works if you reset the blur filter in safari:

```
-webkit-filter: blur(0px);
```

example for all browsers:

```
filter: none; 
-webkit-filter: blur(0px); 
-moz-filter: blur(0px); 
-ms-filter: blur(0px);
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='0');
```

hope it helps

Comment: Why include the other prefixes to fix a Safari only issue?

Comment: for chrome (and I believe Safari), only -webkit-filter: blur(0) is useful

Comment: btw I have to say a big THANK. You saved my day :-)

Comment: There's so many hacks for transform blurs over the years. We're almost in 2016, has this no end?!...This one solved it for me where no other did (appeared in Chrome on OSX).

Comment: While Chrome 77 does automatically resharpen the scaled image, Safari 13.0.1 doesn't and the presented solution does not make Safari resharpen the image either.

Answer (score 11):

For anyone who didn't find the accepted answer useful, adding this on the parent container worked for me:

```
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: This is what finally fixed it for me, particularly putting it on the *parent*. Thank you!

Comment: In my case, I was scaling the image's parent container, and what fixed the blurriness was adding this style to the `img` itself. Thank you!