# Is it possible to avoid blur when scaling down image with transform?

Tags: image, css, css-transforms

I have a background-image set on a div at 100%.

```
<div style="width: 990px; height: 742px; background-image: url('http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/913/cache/deadvlei-africa-namibia_91343_990x742.jpg'); background-size: 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div>
```

When I scale that image down by editing the width/height of the element, it retains its quality.

```
<div style="width: 247.5px; height: 185.5px; background-image: url('http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/913/cache/deadvlei-africa-namibia_91343_990x742.jpg'); background-size: 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div>
```

However, when I scale the image down using `transform: scale`, the image loses quality.

```
<div style="width: 990px; height: 742px; background-image: url('http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/913/cache/deadvlei-africa-namibia_91343_990x742.jpg'); background-size: 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat; transform: scale(.25);"></div>
```

Here is a [demo of the results](http://codepen.io/colmtuite/pen/vNbNGm).

The image only seems to lose quality in webkit browsers. Chrome is worse than Safari.

Does anyone know why the image loses quality using `transform: scale` and if there is a way around it?

Comment: There is no Css there

Comment: There is (transform: scale(.25)), it's just declared as an inline style.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using transform: scale results in blurry images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27060690/using-transform-scale-results-in-blurry-images)

Answer (score 0):

This question has been already asked. Simply set blur filter to 0.
Check [-webkit-transform: scale / blurry images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27060690/webkit-transform-scale-blurry-images)