# Browsers pixelate images when scaling them DOWN

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm designing a website that has a lot of high quality images.  Right now, I've got the images set at 1000px x 1000px.  A majority of them are .png with transparency.  I've noticed that as some browsers  scale **DOWN** the images, they pixelate the images pretty severely.  I've noticed this already in Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge; however, in firefox and chrome the images look great

### Question

---

I was curious if there was a html/css/javascript method of preventing that from happening?

---

I will eventually put a system in place that loads a different size image based on width of window; however, for now I'm hoping there is an easy solution available for this.

**Sorry if this is a duplicate.**  Every time I search for this, people are asking about scaling UP images.  I couldn't find anything about how browsers effect scaling DOWN images that had a solution.

### EDIT

I was asked for the code and I will post the code associated with the images; however, I don't forsee it being a css code issue as it is only effected on certain browers (the two I've noticed are IE and Microsft Edge)

Its fairly basic code

```
#tribox_1 img,#tribox_2 img,#tribox_3 img { clear: left; width: 50%; height: auto; }
```

Comment: Can you replicate this on a fiddle? This might be helpful too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27060690/using-transform-scale-results-in-blurry-images

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: posted the css associated with the images